# Any idea on how to handle 'graphql-redis-subscriptions' authentication when used together with apollo-server

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-subscriptions

I am using 'graphql-redis-subscriptions' from https://github.com/davidyaha/graphql-redis-subscriptions.
Several examples are given on how to setup subscriptions and they actually work but the problem I am facing is how can I authenticate and allow the subscription to be only listened by the logged in client user. I am using Apollo-server for serving graphql apis as following:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
            schema,
            dataSources,
            context: async ({ req, connection }) => {
                if (connection) {
                    return {
                        ...connection.context
                    };
                }

                const token = req.headers[API_TOKEN];

                return {
                    premiumAuth: token
                };
            },
        });
        server.listen(5000);
```

Comment: The subscription web socket endpoint works magically with the addition of following but I. do not understand why?
 ```if (connection) {
                    return {
                        ...connection.context
                    };
                }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticated in the `context` option of `apollo-server` is for an HTTP protocol request authentication. Which means it will protect the `/graphql` endpoint from unauthenticated access. E.g.

```js
  const contextFunction: ContextFunction<IContextFunctionParams, IConnectors<IMemoryDB>> = (
    context: IContextFunctionParams,
  ): Context<IAppContext> => {
    const { req, connection } = context;
    if (connection) {
      return connection.context;
    } else {
      const token: string = validateToken(req);
      const userConnector = new UserConnector<IMemoryDB>(memoryDB);
      let user: IUser | undefined;
      try {
        const userType: UserType = UserType[token];
        user = userConnector.findUserByUserType(userType);
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      return {
        requestingUser: user,
        locationConnector: new LocationConnector<IMemoryDB>(memoryDB),
        userConnector,
        templateConnector: new TemplateConnector<IMemoryDB>(
          memoryDB,
          pubsub,
          // postgresPubSub,
        ),
      };
    }
  };
```

For **WebSocket** protocol connection, which the graphql subscription depends on. 
You need to authenticate inside the `subscriptions.onConnect` method, e.g.

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: contextFunction,
    introspection: true,
    subscriptions: {
      onConnect: (
        connectionParams: IWebSocketConnectionParams,
        webSocket: WebSocket,
        connectionContext: ConnectionContext,
      ) => {
        console.log('websocket connect');
        console.log('connectionParams: ', connectionParams);
        if (connectionParams.token) {
          const token: string = validateToken(connectionParams.token);
          const userConnector = new UserConnector<IMemoryDB>(memoryDB);
          let user: IUser | undefined;
          try {
            const userType: UserType = UserType[token];
            user = userConnector.findUserByUserType(userType);
          } catch (error) {
            throw error;
          }

          const context: ISubscriptionContext = {
            // pubsub: postgresPubSub,
            pubsub,
            subscribeUser: user,
            userConnector,
            locationConnector: new LocationConnector<IMemoryDB>(memoryDB),
          };

          return context;
        }

        throw new Error('Missing auth token!');
      },
      onDisconnect: (webSocket: WebSocket, connectionContext: ConnectionContext) => {
        console.log('websocket disconnect');
      },
    },
  });
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/tree/master/src/subscriptions